# Поиск в строке всех слов длиной не менее 6 символов

Tags: строки, powershell

Необходимо написать сценарий для поиска всех слов длиной не менее 6 символов в строке

**Пример:**

```
.\task5.ps1 "Tue Sep 15 2020 15:39:48 GMT+0300 (Belarus Local Time)"
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

```
Belarus
```

---

**Пробовал следующее**:
через пробел разделить строку в массив и вывести только слова длиной более 6 символов. Что-то с синтаксисом не разобрался до конца

```
data = $args[0] 
$pattern = '\w*[ ():]\w*' 
$matches = [regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).Value 
$str5 = $matches[-1] -split {$_ -eq " "} -join "" $str5 | Where-Object { $_ -match "a-z" } | ForEach-Object{ Matches[0] } 
$str6 = $str5.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.str5.Length -gt 2 } 
$str6
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пробовал следующее через пробел разделить строку в массив и вывести только слова длиной более 6 символов. Что-то с синтаксисом не разобрался до конца  data = $args[0]

$pattern = '\w*[ ():]\w*'

$matches = [regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).Value

$str5 = $matches[-1] -split {$_ -eq " "} -join ""

$str5 | Where-Object { $_ -match "a-z" } | ForEach-Object{ Matches[0] }

$str6 = $str5.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.str5.Length -gt 2 }

$str6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

task5.ps1:

```
$matches = ([regex]'\w{6,}').Matches($args[0])
$matches.Value
```

Команда:

```
.\task5.ps1 "Tue Sep 15 2020 15:39:48 GMT+0300 (Belarus Local Time)"
```

Результат:

```
Belarus
```